# Easy To Learn Advanced Physics

Tags: soft-question, education

I am a first-year undergraduate student and I am looking to do summer research in physics. By the time I finish this year I will have completed intro courses in Mechanics, Electricity and Magnetism, Optics and Thermodynamics. I will also have finished a rigorous sequence of single and multivariable calculus (basically an intro course to Real Analysis). What areas of physics have a decent amount of ongoing research in them but that I can develop a "working knowledge" fairly easily. I do not mind at all learning this on my own or learning additional math that is needed.

Comment: There's a lot of research in the study of the atomic nucleus. Some parts of nuclear physics can be understood easily. Others require lots of QM and more advanced things. My advice is: don't try to run. If you want to be a researcher, you need good marks and lots of knowledge. Start from the beginning: algebra, calculus...

Comment: Realistically, if you insist on doing research that early, the area doesn't actually matter -- you will end up programming or being an experimentalist's assistant. Just about all fields have such opportunities, so just go for what interests you.

Comment: If there were easy lines of inquiring someone would already be working on them. That said, there *are* things that students can do in experimental and observational science. *Scut work:* Repetitive work that requires some understanding but does not require a fully skilled researcher.  *Calibration:* many (but not all) calibration tasks can be done by a trusted student on the basis of physics handed to them by a supervisor. *Programing:* Most tasks need lots of domain specific knowledge, but there are always a few odds and ends if you are already a competent programmer.

Comment: @dmckee too many people repeatedly forget your point.

Comment: The opening of new (sub)fields can offer a brief window when the *"someone else would already be doing it"* rule does not apply, and you can never completely rule out overlooked avenues (but honestly the vast majority of students and amateurs who think they've found one are just fooling themselves; even most pros who think they've found one are wrong).

Comment: I'd remind everyone that comments are not meant for answering questions.

Comment: I would suggest" researching" your *second year* subjects, assuming you pass first year.  Or simply try to understand some everyday things you see in terms of what you know.  Pick something you see at random everyday and try and explain it and model it using what you know.  Forget research.

Comment: @DavidZ The question is already on hold so comments are the only way to make any suggestions.

Comment: @StephenG The purpose of putting the question on hold is _precisely_ to prevent these "suggestions" (answers) from being posted. Just because a question is on hold, that does _not_ mean that the comments become an appropriate venue for posting answers.

Comment: @DavidZ As commenting is not locked when a question is on hold (something the site mechanics could have implemented) I think this is not the intent of "on hold".  It's also very common for comments to be made on questions which are locked and this is usually for constructive reasons.  This is possibly something to discuss in Meta if people feel that strongly about it,  Should "on hold" equate to "no advice" ?

Comment: @StephenG I'm quite confident that I'm correct about the intent of "on hold", and that it's not appropriate to post answers in the comments (cf.the [help center page on commenting](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment)). But I do think it would be a good idea to raise this issue on meta; we shouldn't really continue to discuss it here.